# How to request using api key over a form post method?

Tags: jquery, json

I tried to get the json response using a form using post method, but the I still got forbidden 403.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("Save").onclick = function fun() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["customerAccUserName"].value;
    var Url = "https://url.com/getAccountDetails?format=json&customerAccUserName=" + x;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', Url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization', '123456'");
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        //  alert(xhr.responseText);
        var response1 = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("AccNo").innerHTML = response1.name + ", " + response1.statusCode;
        document.getElementById("AccNo").innerHTML = response1.AccNo;
        document.getElementById("AccNo").innerHTML = response1.AccNo;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got stuck on this, how the right way to put the api key on headers

Thanks for any help :(

Comment: A 403 error means you've not successfully authenticated with the endpoint you're attempting to call. I don't know how you need to authenticate with the API you're using, but I can tell you that putting auth credentials in to a `Content-Type` header is highly likely to be incorrect. I'd suggest you check the API documentation.

Comment: If you're getting bad responses from the server there's nothing we can do by looking at your JS. You'd need to talk to whomever runs the server web service.

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value)` but you're calling it with 4 parameters - doesn't seem right https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

Comment: Try: `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization', '123456'");`

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, tried as you suggest but throw error ' 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present'

Comment: Check the `'` and `"` - it's incorrect in my comment `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "123456");`

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API .

For example:

```js
fetch(`https://url.com/getAccountDetails?format=json&customerAccUserName=${x}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     'api-key-name': 'apikey',
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
.then(response => console.log(response));
```